# AngularJS ng-switch or similar to work with a dynamic values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parse-platform, ng-switch

I have an array in my controller.js. I need that an user insert the input text value and if the right, show one thing and if different show another. I have multiple instances, then I had planned to do with `ng-switch`, but do not let get me the value of a Variable scope. How could I solve it?

**INDEX.html**

```
<body ng-app="formAdictos">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="list in lista"></div>
    <div ng-switch on="lis">
      <input type="text" ng-model="lis">
      <div ng-switch-when="{{lista[0]}}">S</div>
      <div ng-switch-when={{lista[1]}}>Hola</div>
      <div ng-switch-default>Texto para cuando no es ni A ni B</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**controller.js**

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.lista = [];

    $http({method : 'GET',url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/cupon', 
     headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'XXX', 
     'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'XXX'}})
     .success(function(data, status) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++){
            cupo = data.results[i].cupon50;
            $scope.lista[i] = cupo;
        }
        console.log($scope.lista);
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        alert("Error");
    });
}
angular.module('formAdictos').controller('MyController', MyController);`
```

list a array contains three values.

lista = ["hi","good","bad"] this is the result to http call

Comment: Please edit the question to include the JSON returned from your $http call.

Comment: $scope.lista = ["hi","good","bad"] this is the result

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't really the switch directive and it doesn't seemed to work so i came with something else.

```js
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.lista = [];
   $scope.lis = "";
   $scope.lista = [{key:"hi", value:"S"}, {key:"good", value:"Hola"}] ;
   $scope.isInList = false;
   $scope.checkIsInList = function(lis){
     $scope.isInList = false;
     for(var i =0; i < $scope.lista.length; i++){
         if($scope.lista[i].key === lis){
             $scope.isInList = true;
             return;
         }
     }
   }
}
angular.module('formAdictos', []).controller('MyController', MyController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="formAdictos">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
       <input type="text" ng-model="lis" ng-change="checkIsInList(lis)">
       <div ng-repeat="item in lista">
          <div ng-if="item.key == lis"><span ng-bind="item.value"></span></div>
    </div>
   <div ng-if="isInList==false">Texto para cuando no es ni A ni B</div>
     lis : {{lis}}
   </div>
 
</div>
```

This work as intended, I have to manage the default using a boolean.

However as you can see, you will need to merge your list from your server with the list of matching value in a list of objects to make it works like i did. Another way would be to have 2 array where matches have the same index an use the `$index` provided by `ng-repeat`

Comment: Thanks my friend...It is similar to what I wanted. I could use it.